# Yahoo Pipes: Possible to retrieve get real url from feedproxy.google.com url?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

Using Yahoo Pipes, is it possible to poll this url
http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/Techcrunch/~3/P-_qWQXyAPU/
and get the real url
http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/12/08/build-it-with-me
returned to the pipe?

Ideally the solution would be generic enough to poll any url and get it's "real" url.
I'm thinking it might be possible with YQL but am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for completeness, I thought I would link the answer you got on YDN:

> http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=3993&st=0&p=10927&#entry10927
>
> If you use ***y.rest()*** to make the call you can use ***followRedirects(false)***
>   like this:
>
> ```
> use 'http://javarants.com/yql/javascript.xml'as j; select * from j where code='response.object =
> y.rest("http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/Techcrunch/~3/P-%5FqWQXyAPU/").followRedirects(false).get().headers.location;'
> ```
>
> Sam

Comment: Yup.  This worked great.  I should have come back to post it myself.  Thanks Gavin.