# Short URL to Long URL Function in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to find the proper way in PHP of creating a short URL to long URL convertor function.

I think @yes123 is onto something in his function on [Regex / php code to check if a URL is a short URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557116/regex-php-code-to-check-if-a-url-is-a-short-url) but not too sure.

Comment: Uhm, who and **why** deleted my comment?! @andrebruton: do you have any particular question? short url is just a random string, nothing more

Comment: Not me, trying to find a solution. I want a function that inputs a short URL like http://bit.ly/xyz and returns the long URL like http://www.cnn.com/etc

Comment: Have a look at YQL .

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970606/yahoo-pipes-possible-to-retrieve-get-real-url-from-feedproxy-google-com-url

Answer (score 0):

The http://longurl.org/ site has an API which you can call from your app.

Comment: Looks interesting... but can't I just use a simple function to do this.

Comment: No, a "simple function" is not enough. Every URL shortener service has a database, and a short URL is nothing more than an index into that database. An HTTP request to the short URL server does a database lookup and returns the target URL in a redirect.

Comment: Hi Greg, I understand that, but all I need is a function where I feed it the short URL, PHP goes and gets the headers with something like $headers = get_headers($url,1); and returns the long url for me. All I want to do is display the long url instead of the short url. No need for databases on my side...

Comment: Right. You need to use the [LongURL API](http://longurl.org/api). They even give examples for PHP.

Comment: There isn't a COMPLETE example on the API website. Here is a complete working example using http://longurl.org  http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/expandir-urls-acortadas-con-php-y-longurl.org-c97773l/

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, I think. I created a function to read the headers and return the Location. I might have to add some error checking but I'll have to investigate how.

```
<?php
$shortURL = "http://bit.ly/I2ClnP";
// Should return http://www.ericvalli.com/index.php?/stories/off-the-grid/
echo "Short URL: " . $shortURL . "<br>";

echo "Long URL: " . long_url($shortURL) . "<br>";

function long_url($url) {
  $longURL = get_headers($url, 7);
  return $longURL['Location'];
}
?>
```

I tried using `stream_context_set_default($options)`; but that function doesn't seem to work on all servers.

If anyone has any ideas on how to do error checking, that would be great.